# Unable to Process File with multiple delimiters in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am unable to process a file, which has records with multiple delimiters.
My file has records like 1,jhon 20000.
I tried with below given pig script

```
outerbag = load 'file location ' using PigStorage(',') as (eid,edteail);
innerbag = FOREACH outerbag GENERATE eid, FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(edetails,'\t'));
dump innerbag;
```

I am getting output as :

```
 (1,)
 (2,)
```

and so on.

how can i get proper output as : `(1,jhon   20000)`

Comment: can you please format your code?

Comment: above commands i am executing on grunt shell and file is getting processed but not getting the desired output. How you want me to format these commands ?

Comment: In the record above, is "jhon" and "20000" tab separated?

Comment: I executed your script as is and got the output: (1,jhon,20000)

Comment: I am using Pig Version 8. i am not getting output because of low version i am using ???

Answer (score 0):

```
A =  LOAD 'folder/file';

B = FOREACH A GENERATE FALTTEN(
REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL($0,'(.*),(.*) (.*)'));
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

The variable name used in the first line and the second line is different for `edetails`.

Try,

```
outerbag = load 'file location ' using PigStorage(',') as (eid,edetails);
innerbag = FOREACH outerbag GENERATE eid, FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(edetails,'\t'));
dump innerbag;
```